# How to fork a child process that listens on a different debug port than the parent

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use `child_process.fork` to spawn a process that breaks and listens on the V8 debug protocol.

However, I can't get the forked process to listen on a port that's different from the parent process. Assuming the parent process listens on `6000`, the child process also attempts to listen on port `6000`:

> Failed to open socket on port 6000, waiting 1000 ms before retrying

Here's my code:

```
// `test.js`, invoked as `node --debug-brk=6000 test.js`

var nodeModule, args, env, child

nodeModule = path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app.js'))

args = [
    '--debug-brk=6001'
  , '127.0.0.1'
  , 3030
  , 'api-testing'
]

env = { 'DB_URI': 'mongodb://localhost/test' }

child = require('child_process')
  .fork(nodeModule, args, {env: env})
  .on('message', callback)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the forked process to listen on port `6001`, but the child process attempts to listen on port `6000` which is in use by the parent.

**How can I get the child process to listen on port `6001`, or some other free port?**

There are several threads on this subject. For example:

- [How to debug Node.JS child forked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process)
- [Debugging Node.js processes with cluster.fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691554/debugging-node-js-processes-with-cluster-fork)

However:

- These threads deal with the `cluster` variant of forking
- Refer to `execArgv`, which appear to [have been undocumented for `process`](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5534) and are still undocumented for `cluster`.

Answer (score 10):

Simple enough answer, found on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process#comment24317454_16843277) and with some help from #Node.js on Freenode:

Just move the `--debug-brk` into the `execArgv` key of the `options` param to `fork`:

```
// Excerpt:

args = [
   '127.0.0.1'
  , 3030
  , 'api-testing'
]

env = { 'DB_URI': 'mongodb://localhost/test' }

child = fork(nodeModule, args, {
    env: env
  , execArgv: ['--debug-brk=6001']
})
  .on('message', this.callback)
```

`execArgv` is the array of parameters passed to the node process. `argv` is the set passed to the main module. There's a dedicated parameter to `child_process.fork` for `argv`, but `execArgv`s have to be placed within the `opts` param. This works, and in the child process we have:

```
> process.execArgv 
["--debug-brk=6001"]
> process.argv
["/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.13/bin/node" "/Users/dmitry/dev/linksmotif/app.js", "127.0.0.1", "3030", "api-testing"]
```

**In summary**

Node.js consistently treats `execArgv` and `argv` as separate sets of values.

Comment: In addition, passing "--debug-brk" without specifying the port will make Node pick up a free port automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Before to fork remove old `debug-brk` parameter :

```
process.execArgv = process.execArgv.filter(function(o){ 
    var x = "--debug-brk"; 
    return o.substring(0, x.length) !== x
});
```

and add a new one:

```
process.execArgv.push("--debug-brk=9999");
```