# Koa + Webpack + HMR server can't be debugged

Tags: node.js, webpack, webstorm, koa

I've built a Koa server that uses koa-webpack-middleware in order to allow compilation and HMR. It runs fine if I invoke `server.js` directly. However, I run into problems if I try to debug it by launching `server.js` using a debug profile in WebStorm.

When I run it normally, it gives the normal output for clean-webpack-plugin, then stops for a few seconds, then gives a message that it has compiled.

When I run it in WebStorm, the latter message never comes, and the server doesn't start. Why is this happening?

Edit: This effect is only observed if I click debug on the profile, and not when I click run (in WebStorm).

Comment: similar problems may occur when running with `--debug-brk` (i.e. when debugging) if the spawned child process uses the same debug port as a parent process - as a result the forked process is suspended and the application 'stalls'.

Comment: @lena what can I do about this?

Comment: check the way child processes are forked in your code - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252310/how-to-fork-a-child-process-that-listens-on-a-different-debug-port-than-the-pare, for example. Note that it is not necessary a problem in your own code, it can be th issue with koa-webpack-middleware, etc.

Comment: @lena as far as I can tell, no child processes are being created at all. when I run it with the debug-brk option from PowerShell, and then attach to it from the chrome debugger, it works perfectly. it just doesn't work in webstorm

Comment: child processes are definitely forked - webpack tasks, etc. Anyway, I can hardly help further unless you can provide a project that shows up the issue

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I had Webstorm set to break on all exceptions. This created a huge problem while debugging, because the initializer for the Webpack middleware throws hundreds and hundreds of exceptions and then catches them. However, Webstorm just hangs the process because it is set to avoid stepping into non-user code.

The solution that ended up working for me was to go into the breakpoint settings, and check the box that says uncaught only (which was the intended behaviour in the first place).